# Using canvas for custom google map marker. (v3)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I did custom markers using canvas for google maps engine. It's work fine for firefox, opera and chrome. It's not works for internet explorer. I'im using fxcanvas library for ie but it require jooscript. Conflict's occures between jooscript and google maps.
When i drag map i get still the same error:

"Error: Not correct argument,
Url: http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/pll_ALL/mapfiles/api/3/5/7a/main.js"

Comment: You need to frame this as a question and not a statement.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occured in eventHandler function. I made bugFix so now is everything ok. I don't know when author(Evgeny Burzak) of jooscript implement bugfix but it is accepted:)